# Given a singly linked list of integers, reverse the nodes of the linked list 'k' at a time and return its modified list

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list, reverse

i am writing the input with expected input and output and what i am getting...pls solve for input as k=0..i am attaching the code here...

input 1
1
4 5 7 8 3 36 -1
6
correct output 1
36 3 8 7 5 4 (which i am getting)

input 2
1
4 5 7 8 3 36 -1
0
expected output which i am not getting
4 5 7 8 3 36

````
def kReverse(head, k):
   current = head
   next = None
   prev = None
   count = 0
   while (current is not None and count < k):
       next = current.next
       current.next = prev
       prev = current
       current = next
       count += 1
   if next is not None:
       head.next = kReverse(next, k)
   return prev
    ```
````

Comment: Can you clarify your input?  From what I gather you are given  L = to a sequence of integers and a value k < len(L) and you want to reverse the order of L begining at the index specified by K.  Is this a correct interpretation?

Comment: yes and for any value of k it is working except for k=0....Given a singly linked list of integers, reverse the nodes of the linked list 'k' at a time and return its modified list.
 'k' is a positive integer and is less than or equal to the length of the linked list. If the number of nodes is not a multiple of 'k,' then left-out nodes, in the end, should be reversed as well.@itprorh66

Comment: The reason you are not getting the correct answer for K=0 is that your function doesn't handle the case, it looks to me like for k=0 you are returning the original value of prev = None.. Is this the case?

Comment: @itprorh66 thanks man it was returning prev for zero....and now its returning current if its zero...thanks a lot man

Answer (score 0):

this code will not run because you are recursively reversing every node in k group. But the question says: "If the number of nodes is not a multiple of k then left-out nodes, in the end, should remain as it is"

I run your code on leetcode: this is the given linked list:

[image]

You are reversing each linked list in k group and ignoring if the last part of the linked list less than k or not. This is your outcome:

[image]

this should be the outcome:

[image]

here is my solution:

```
class Solution:
    def reverse_kth(self,head:ListNode,k:int)->ListNode:
        # create dumy node and point to the head
        dummy=ListNode(0,head)
        group_prev=dummy
        while True:
            kth=self.get_kth(group_prev,k)
            # if I cannot partition the last part, break out of the loop
            if not kth:
                break
            group_next=kth.next
            #reversing the group with two pointer
            # 1-2---kth  --- kth.next  we dont want to break the link
            prev, cur=kth.next,group_prev.next
            while cur!=group_next:
                temp=cur.next
                cur.next=prev
                prev=cur
                cur=temp
            #  this temp is the first node in the group
            temp=group_prev.next
            group_prev.next=kth
            group_prev=temp
        return dummy.next
    # partition the linked list
    def get_kth(self,cur,k):
        while cur and k>0:
            cur=cur.next
            k-=1
        return cur
```